# Map only changed properties?

Tags: c#, automapper

Using AutoMapper, is it possible to map only the changed properties from the View Model to the Domain Object?

The problem I am coming across is that if there are properties on the View Model that are not changed (null), then they are overwriting the Domain Objects and getting persisted to the database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, but you have to specify when to skip the destination property using `Condition()` in your mapping configuration.

Here's an example. Consider the following classes:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Map { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The first map won't overwrite `destination.Text`, but the second will.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Text, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Map));

var source = new Source { Text = "Do not map", Map = false };
var destination = new Destination { Text = "Leave me alone" };
Mapper.Map(source, destination);
source.Map = true;
var destination2 = new Destination { Text = "I'll be overwritten" };
Mapper.Map(source, destination2);
```

Answer (score 6):

@Matthew Steven Monkan is correct, but seems AutoMapper changed API. I will put new one for others refer.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapOnlyIfChanged<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
    {
        map.ForAllMembers(source =>
        {
            source.Condition((sourceObject, destObject, sourceProperty, destProperty) =>
            {
                if (sourceProperty == null)
                    return !(destProperty == null);
                return !sourceProperty.Equals(destProperty);
            });
        });
        return map;
    }
```

that's all

Answer (score 2):

## For Automapper version < 6.0

Yes; I wrote this extension method to map only dirty values from a model to Entity Framework.

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapOnlyIfDirty<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
{
    map.ForAllMembers(source =>
    {
        source.Condition(resolutionContext =>
        {
            if (resolutionContext.SourceValue == null)
                return !(resolutionContext.DestinationValue == null);
            return !resolutionContext.SourceValue.Equals(resolutionContext.DestinationValue);
        });
    });
    return map;
}
```

Example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model, Domain>().MapOnlyIfDirty();
```

Comment: SourceValue is not an available member of resolutioncontext.  What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, these members "SourceValue" and "DestinationValue" are not available for me either.

Answer (score -1):

No.

This is exactly one of the reasons you never map from viewmodel to domain model.  Domain/business model changes are too important for a tool to handle.

Automapper is not designed to handle this scenario:

> AutoMapper works because it enforces a convention. It assumes that
>   your destination types are a subset of the source type. It assumes
>   that everything on your destination type is meant to be mapped. It
>   assumes that the destination member names follow the exact name of the
>   source type. It assumes that you want to flatten complex models into
>   simple ones.

From: https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/

---

Manually:

```
customer.LastName = viewModel.LastName
```

Changing business state is too important to do otherwise.

Comment: What? I thought this is exactly what this is for? Please elaborate how you transform your Domain Objects to your View Models.

Comment: What I meant to say in the above was how do you get your Edit/View Models back to your Domain Objects?

Comment: Do you do this in your controllers?

Comment: downvote. What you should not do is to let AutoMapper do it automatically. But if you are indeed in control of what you are doing is a very useful tool.

Comment: @Sam, you manually map them.  Automapper is not designed to go from subset to superset.