# How to map only changed properties using Automapper and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

I know that this question [had been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781099/map-only-changed-properties/) already, but those answers didn't work for me. So, I beg not to close this question!

The goal is simple:

1. Get entity from database using Entity Framework.
2. Pass this entity to MVC view.
3. Edit entity on the page.
4. Save entity.

*What I have*:

### Entities

• `Client` relates to table in database.

• `ClientDto` is the same as `Client`, but without `Comment` property (to emulate situation when user must not see this field).

```cs
public class Client
{
  public string TaskNumber { get; set; }
  public DateTime CrmRegDate { get; set; }
  public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDto
{
  public string TaskNumber { get; set; }
  public DateTime CrmRegDate { get; set; }
}
```

### Database table

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.client
(
  task_number  varchar(50)   NOT NULL,
  crm_reg_date date          NOT NULL,
  comment      varchar(3000)     NULL
);

-- Seeding
INSERT INTO dbo.client VALUES
('1001246', '2010-09-14', 'comment 1'),
('1001364', '2010-09-14', 'comment 2'),
('1002489', '2010-09-22', 'comment 3');
```

### MVC controller

```cs
public class ClientsController : Controller
{
  private readonly ILogger logger;
  private readonly TestContext db;
  private IMapper mapper;

  public ClientsController(TestContext db, IMapper mapper, ILogger<ClientsController> logger)
  {
    this.db = db;
    this.logger = logger;
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    var clients = db.Clients;
    var clientsDto = mapper.ProjectTo<ClientDto>(clients);
    return View(model: clientsDto);
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string taskNumber)
  {
    var client = await db.Clients.FindAsync(taskNumber);
    return View(model: client);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ClientDto clientDto)
  {
    // For now it's empty - it'll be used for saving entity
  }
}
```

### Mappings:

```cs
builder.Services
  .AddAutoMapper(config =>
  {
    config.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
    config.CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>();
  }
```

### Helper (outputs entity entry as JSON)

```cs
internal static class EntititesExtensions
{
  internal static string ToJson<TEntity>(this EntityEntry<TEntity> entry) where TEntity: class
  {
    var states = from member in entry.Members
                 select new
                 {
                   State = Enum.GetName(member.EntityEntry.State),
                   Name = member.Metadata.Name,
                   Value = member.CurrentValue
                 };
    var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(states);
    return json.ToJsonString(new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
  }
}
```

## THE PROBLEM

I need to map only changed properties from `ClientDto` to `Client` in `Edit(ClientDto clientDto)`.

### Which solutions were used

#### Solution 1

Just map `ClientDto` to `Client`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ClientDto clientDto)
{
  var client = mapper.Map<Client>(clientDto);
  logger.LogInformation(db.Entry(client).ToJson());
  db.Update(client);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  return View(viewName: "Success");
}
```

The problem with this code is that absolutely new `Client` entity gets created which properties will be filled by `ClientDto`. This means that `Comment` property will be `NULL` and it will make `NULL` the column `comment` in database. In general case, all hidden properties (i.e. absent in DTO) will have their default values. *Not good.*

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "State": "Detached",
    "Name": "TaskNumber",
    "Value": "1001246"
  },
  {
    "State": "Detached",
    "Name": "Comment",
    "Value": null
  },
  {
    "State": "Detached",
    "Name": "CrmRegDate",
    "Value": "2010-09-15T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

#### Solution 2

I tried to use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781099/map-only-changed-properties/49975511#49975511) from the answer I mentioned above:

```cs
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapOnlyIfChanged<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
{
  map.ForAllMembers(source =>
  {
    source.Condition((sourceObject, destObject, sourceProperty, destProperty) =>
    {
      if (sourceProperty == null)
        return !(destProperty == null);
      return !sourceProperty.Equals(destProperty);
    });
  });
  return map;
}
```

In configuration:

```cs
builder.Services
  .AddAutoMapper(config =>
  {
    config.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
    config.CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>().MapOnlyIfChanged();
  });
```

Running same code as in solution 1, we get the same output (`Comment` is `null`):

```json
[
  {
    "State": "Detached",
    "Name": "TaskNumber",
    "Value": "1001246"
  },
  {
    "State": "Detached",
    "Name": "Comment",
    "Value": null
  },
  {
    "State": "Detached",
    "Name": "CrmRegDate",
    "Value": "2010-09-15T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

*Not good.*

### Solution 3

Let's take another route:

1. Obtain entity from database.
2. Use non-generic `Map` in order to overwrite the values from `ClientDto` to `Client` from database.
3. Tune mapping configuration in order to skip properties which values are equal.

```cs
builder.Services
  .AddAutoMapper(config =>
  {
    config.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
    config.CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>()
      .ForMember(
        dest => dest.TaskNumber,
        opt => opt.Condition((src, dest) => src.TaskNumber != dest.TaskNumber))
      .ForMember(
        dest => dest.TaskNumber,
        opt => opt.Condition((src, dest) => src.CrmRegDate != dest.CrmRegDate));
  });
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ClientDto clientDto)
{
  var dbClient = await db.Clients.FindAsync(clientDto.TaskNumber);
  logger.LogInformation(db.Entry(dbClient).ToJson());
  mapper.Map(
    source: clientDto,
    destination: dbClient,
    sourceType: typeof(ClientDto),
    destinationType: typeof(Client)
  );
  logger.LogInformation(db.Entry(dbClient).ToJson());
  db.Update(dbClient);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  return View(viewName: "Success");
}
```

This *finally works*, but it has problem - it still modifies *all* properties. Here's the output:

```json
[
  {
    "State": "Modified",
    "Name": "TaskNumber",
    "Value": "1001246"
  },
  {
    "State": "Modified",
    "Name": "Comment",
    "Value": "comment 1"
  },
  {
    "State": "Modified",
    "Name": "CrmRegDate",
    "Value": "2010-09-15T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

So, how to make Automapper update only modified properties?

Comment: My first remark would be: then do it without AutoMapper. Also, if the entity can return from the UI without comment and other properties that apparently can't be null while they can't be null in the database *and* they can't have default values, then there's already something wrong on that side. Maybe I'm missing something but isn't the only thing left then that the user should supply values?

Comment: Just remove `db.Update(dbClient);`. EF will detect which properties are changed automatically.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Man, you saved me! Create the answer and I'll give ya +1000!  Can you explain how it works? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to call `context.Update()` explicitly.

When loading entity, EF remember every original values for every mapped property.

Then when you change property, EF will compare current properties with original and create appropriate update SQL only for changed properties.

For further reading: [Change Tracking in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution 2 has a bug.  Why bother mapping null on null?

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapOnlyIfChanged<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
{
  map.ForAllMembers(source =>
  {
    source.Condition((sourceObject, destObject, sourceProperty, destProperty) =>
    {
      if (sourceProperty == null)
        return false;
      return !sourceProperty.Equals(destProperty);
    });
  });
  return map;
}
```